# A graph with single circle

Tags: graph-theory, terminology

Is there a name for a (directed) graph that has exactly one circuit that goes through all of its vertices (in the same direction)? If so, what is it called? Example is as follows:

$$A\to B, B \to C, C \to A$$

where the set of vertices is $A, B, C$.

Comment: A directed cycle?

Comment: @TheNumber23 No. I am not asking the name/property of a cycle. I am asking the name/property of a graph.

Comment: It is called [directed cycle graph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cycle_graph#Directed_cycle_graph).